# Searching for a string in Column Values

Tags: sql, ms-access-2007

I am writing a simple query which will give me file id's of all files whose name are matching to the given string

for example in `Files` table

```
FileID      FileName
------------------------
1           File1.html
2           Keys.doc
3           Fruits.xls
5           Ffinger.mp3
```

and here is the query i have tried but its not working

```
SELECT FileId FROM Files WHERE  FileName Like '% ｆ %'
```

I am expecting this query to return file id's of all files whoes name contain `f` or `F`

I am using MS-Access 2007

Comment: MS Access wild card is nearly always *, not %

Comment: @Remou ; sorry i didn't understood ur comment...

Comment: `FileName Like "*f*"`, keep 'nearly always' in mind, not 'always'.

Comment: Also, you are searching for a string ' f ' the white space is not removed. So, none of your file names follow the pattern that you have searched for.